# Display barcode with TYPE('X','B') > Barcode with TYPE('A')

Tags: sql-server

Everyone I just want to display BARCODE with TYPE('B','X') **>** BARCODE with TYPE('A'). also I don't want to display ITEM with only one BARCODE.

This script is only for displaying barcode with type ('X','B',A'),Because I don't know what the best Condition fit on my request.

```
select ITEM,BARCODE,TYPE,STOCKNO. from [DWSTAGE].[INVUPC]
where type in ('X','B','A') 
order by item
```

in my Sample query result.
My unique TYPE for barcode is 'A'.  And for ('X','B') is intended only for additional barcode under ITEM.
But problem is TYPE A must > 'B','X'.

```
    ITEM              | BARCODE             | TYPE   | STOCKNO.
    ---------------------------------------------------
    12458         |  481181880922       |   A    | 3464
    12458         |  481181880924       |   X    | 3464
    12458         |  481181880926       |   X    | 3464
    30689         |  485481881862       |   B    | 231
    30699         |  485481881861       |   A    | 231
    30699         |  485481881863       |   X    | 231
    11449         |  483981889371       |   A    | 532
    44775         |  480081880924       |   A    | 871
    44775         |  480081880922       |   X    | 871
```

Expected Result
display only those barcode with type('B','X') > barcode with type 'A'.

```
    ITEM            | BARCODE                | TYPE |   STOCKNO.
    ---------------------------------------------------
    12458         |  481181880924       |   X    | 3464
    12458         |  481181880926       |   X    | 3464
    30689         |  485481881862       |   B    | 231
    30699         |  485481881863       |   X    | 231
```

Does anyone have any idea on this? Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you add more details about your logic or request?

Comment: when you say ```barcode with type('B','X') > barcode with type 'A'.```, do you mean the ```BARCODE``` column or the ```STOCKNO``` column to be compared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self join back same table and check for the `iupc` value for `A`. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is required as you have cases where `A` does not exists for a `inumbr`

```
SELECT I.*
FROM   INVUPC I
       LEFT JOIN INVUPC A ON   I.inumbr = A.inumbr 
                          AND  I.iupc <> A.iupc
                          AND  A.iupccd = 'A'
WHERE  I.iupccd <> 'A'
AND    (
           I.iupc > A.iupc 
       OR  A.inumbr IS NULL
       )
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0211ad6ff3957b183dfa8238af1bb5ff)

Comment: thank you for this, it solves my problem. by the way what if , if I add type 'C' to not to be included in result, how to do this... Thanks a lot for your time .